# Athena removing delimiter in output CSV files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I'm using Athena to write some gzip files to S3.

## Query

```sql
CREATE TABLE NODES_GZIPPED_NODESTEST5
WITH (
      external_location = 'my-bucket',
      format = 'TEXTFILE',
 )
AS SELECT col1, col2
FROM ExistingTableIHave
LIMIT 10;
```

The table is just 2 columns, but when I create this table and check the external_location, the files are missing the comma delimiter between the data. How can I ensure the CSVs it writes to S3 keep the commas?

Answer (score 4):

You can add a `field_delimiter` to the `WITH` expression.

From the [AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/create-table-as.html) docs:

> Optional and specific to text-based data storage formats. The single-character field delimiter for files in `CSV`, `TSV`, and text files. For example, `WITH (field_delimiter = ',')`. Currently, multicharacter field delimiters are not supported for CTAS queries. If you don't specify a field delimiter, `\001` is used by default.

Comment: I saw this and tried it. After doing so, I was unable to decompress any of the gzip files